# Infinite loader issue on Vue + NGINX deployment on AKS

Tags: docker, vue.js, kubernetes, nginx, vue-cli

I have deployed a Vue-CLI Frontend on AKS.

When I run my app in Dev mode using `npm run serve` on AKS, it runs as intended and serves all the requests.

However, when I deploy a Production build, using `npm run build` and then serving the `dist` folder through NGINX, **on some of the pages** I am getting an infinite loader without returning to the back screen as shown below:
[image]

This is only observed on 2 of the pages on sub-paths like `https:\\example.com\details\view-users` and `https:\\example.com\details\return`

This is my **Dockerfile**:

```
# Use Ubuntu 20.04 LTS as the base image
FROM ubuntu:20.04

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Update the package list and install necessary packages
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y nginx && \
    apt-get install -y curl gnupg2 && \
    curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs && \
    npm install -g vue-cli

# Copy the Vue.js app files to the container
COPY . /app

# Build the Vue.js app for production
RUN npm install && \
    npm run build

# Copy the Nginx configuration file to the container
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Expose port 80 for incoming web traffic
EXPOSE 8080

# Start Nginx and keep the container running
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Here's my **nginx.conf**:

```
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
  server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  example.com;
    error_log stderr;
    access_log /dev/stdout;
    location / {
      root   /app/dist;
      index  index.html;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
  }
}
```

What could be the reason of this behavior on specific pages and what can I do to resolve it?

Comment: Refer to this [Gitlink](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/310) helpful to resolve your issue

Comment: I am getting almost all the subpages except few that I mentioned. 
I tried adding 
`module.exports = {
  publicPath: ''
}` but it isn't working either.

Comment: Please, pay attention to the browser console, does it log any errors? The error probably has nothing to do with Kubernetes by itself, but for the Vue build result.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is about how the VueRouter is handling the routing. In dev mode built in dev server handles routing. But in production you use nginx as a web server. Probably adding this new config to your nginx.conf file will solve your problem.

```
location /details {
  root   /app/dist;
  index  index.html;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```